# Getting a TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined when refreshing the page using react hooks

Tags: mongodb, react-hooks, strapi

The first time I run the code it fetches the data fine but after refreshing or going to another page and then back I get the type error

I am using react and strapi.js as my CMS with a mongoDB for my backend. Wasn't sure if this was because of some interaction between the stack but like I said it works once and then crashes until I make updates to my code.

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';



export function Home() {

  const [testData, setTestData] = useState([])

  async function fetchTest() {
    const response = await fetch(
        'https://strapi-mongo-backend.herokuapp.com/Posts'
    )
  
    const json = await response.json()
  
    setTestData(json)
  }

  useEffect(()=> {
    fetchTest()
  },[])

  console.log(testData[1])

  return (
    <div className="Home">
      <Link to="/admin"><h1>Hello{testData[1].Description}</h1></Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The first time I run the code it fetches the data fine but after refreshing or going to another page and then back I get the type error

Can you double confirm that, when you refresh/get back, the HTTP request is always being sent?

A suggestion to avoid the type error would be, only render `{testData[1].Description}` when testData is not `undefined`. That is to say, change rendering part to

```
return (
    <div className="Home">
      <Link to="/admin"><h1>Hello{testData && testData[1].Description}</h1></Link>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately, it does the same thing when I added that bit of code. If I delete the call to object and paste again it shows up once but when I refresh the page or go back from another page it will crash unless I delete the code once again.